# mysqldump from a remote server

Tags: pipe, mysql

I need to copy mysql db from a remote server to a local server.
The only way I can get access to that DB is by connecting to a remote computer (let's call it X) with ssh, and then from that computer I connect to mysql with `mysql -h address -u username -p password`. My limitation is that I cannot do the dump on the mysql server that runs the DB, and cannot do the dump to computer X (for administrative reason that cannot be change).

Is there a way to tell mysql to do the dump directly to my local server? (Perhaps using PIPE, though I'm not familiar with it).
For what it's worth, my server runs on Ubuntu server, X is also running on linux.

I tried looking for a solution but couldn't find something to this exact scenario.

Appreciate any help.

Regards,
Elad

Comment: You could try to use sshfs and map a remote folder (perhaps your local pc if it is accessible) on the mysql server. then use that for the dump. (i'm assuming here you're using a linux mysql server)

Comment: You can tell ssh to run a command on the remote machine, then redirect the output to a file on your local computer

Answer (score 10):

You can use the STDIN/STDOUT redirection feature of SSH:

```
$ ssh user@remote "mysqldump -h host -u username -p dbname" > dbname.sql
```

With this command, `mysqldump` writes its dump to STDOUT, which is redirected to the STDOUT of your local shell. With `> dbname.sql` you write the stream of STDOUT to the local file.

You can even pipe the output via gzip (or any other compression tool) to reduce bandwidth if you like:

```
$ ssh user@remote "mysqldump -h host -u username -p dbname | gzip" | gunzip > dbname.sql
```

You can also use the pipe the other way round to restore a database from the backup:

```
$ gzip dbname.sql | ssh user@remote "gunzip | mysql -h host -u username -p dbname"
```

Or remotely restore without compression (not recommended):

```
$ dbname.sql > ssh user@remote "mysql -h host -u username -p dbname"
```

Comment: what about restoring with this method?

Comment: @NathanQ well, on the local side of the pipe the data is first sent to `gzip`, then to `ssh`, on the remote server then to `gunzip`, and finally reaches the destination `mysql` (third example)

Answer (score 3):

You can use SSH's tunneling feature:

```
ssh server-x -L 12345:remote-db-server:3306
```

This will tell the SSH client to listen for TCP connections to port 12345 on the local machine (the one you're connecting from), and to relay them as connections from `server-x` to port 3306 (the default MySQL server port) on `remote-db-server`.

Then you can just run `mysqldump` on your local computer, and tell it to connect to `localhost` port 12345.  It'll actually be connecting to the remote database server, and from that server's perspective it'll look like the connection is coming from `server-x`.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to do this without having to save the data to an intermediate dump file. You can also make it go faster by compressing the data as it streams. This command connects to the remote server over ssh, and runs `mysqldump` on a named database. `mysqldump` pipes its output to standard output, so we pipe that into `gzip`, which we tell to output to stdout as well, and compress using factor 9. That compressed output is then streamed over ssh back to the local machine, where it is uncompressed and piped into `mysql` targeting a local database of the same name (which will be overwritten because `mysqldump` will add `drop database` commands to the dump file by default):

```
ssh remote.example.com "mysqldump dbname | gzip -q -c -9" | gunzip -q | mysql dbname
```

You can get SSH to do the compression for you, but performance and compression ratio may not be quite as good:

```
ssh -C remote.example.com "mysqldump dbname" | mysql dbname
```

With either method, no intermediate dump file is created, so disk space requirements are lower.

For better performance you might want to try using `zstd` or `pigz` for the compression.